# Error while installing gulp-sass on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I creating my new web and this is the first time I'm using gulp and I have problems with the installation itself.
I used `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`
and I got this

```
E:\WebPages\MyPage>npm install gulp-sass

> node-sass@3.13.1 install E:\WebPages\MyPage\node_modules\gulp-
sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-    
sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-59_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-
sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-59_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or how to install gulp-sass?
Thanks

Comment: `npm rebuild node-sass`, then `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have an updated version of node and npm running.
See https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1911 for more possible solutions.

Comment: Nice feel free to star the answer